# Java: strange order of queue made from priority queue

Tags: java, priority-queue

I wrote a maze solving program which is supposed to support DFS, BFS, A*, Dijkstra's, and greedy algorithm. Anyway, I chose PriorityQueue for my frontier data structure since I thought a priority can behave like a queue, stack, or priority queue depends on the implementation of the comparator.

This is how I implemented my comparator to turn the priority queue into a queue:

/**Since the "natural ordering" of a priority queue has the least element at the head and a conventional comparator returns -1 when the first is less than the second, the hacked comparator always return 1 so that the current (last) square will be placed at the tail (this should work recursively)**/

```
public int compare(Square square1, Square square2)
{
    return 1;
}
```

However, my solution for the maze was not optimal after I did a BFS.

The maze starts at top right corner with coordinate (35,1) and my program checks the left, then up, then down, then right neighbour.
Here are the println I did:

polled out (35,1)

added (34,1)

added (35,2)

polled out (34,1)

added (33,1)

added (34,2)

polled out (35,2)

added (35,3)

polled out (33,1)

added (32,1)

added (33,2)

polled out (34,2)

add (34,3)

poll out (32,1)

......

Notice in a BFS (35,3) should be polled out before (32,1) since the former is added into the queue before the latter. What really confused me is that the data structure behaved like a queue--all new members were added from the back--until I added (32,1), which was placed at the head of the queue.

I thought my comparator should force the priority queue to put new comers in the back. What is even stranger to me is that the data structure changed its nature from a queue to a stack in the middle.

Many thanks to you guys ahead and sorry about my poor English,
Sincerely,
Sean

Comment: Your comparator should just negate the usual return if you want to reverse the ordering. Returning a constant '1' cannot possibly work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you've implemented `compare` is wrong, and would only work if it's called only in a very specific way that you're assuming.  However, you have no idea in what context the `PriorityQueue` actually calls `compare`.  The `compare` function might well be called on an existing element inside the data structure, instead of the new one, or vice versa.

(Even if you did read the source code and traced it and found that this particular implementation works in a certain way, you shouldn't depend on that if you want your code to be maintainable.  At the least, you'd be making yourself more work by having to explain why it works.)

You could just use some sort of counter and assign it as the value for each added item, then implement `compare` correctly based on the value.

A correct implementation of `compare` might look like this:

```
int compare(Object x, Object y){
    return x.getSomeProperty() - y.getSomeProperty();
}
```

Note that if you switch the order of the parameters, the answer will change as well.  No, the int returned does *not* necessarily have to come from {-1, 0, 1}.  The spec calls for 0, or a negative or positive integer.  You can use any one you wish, so long as it's the correct sign.

Comment: In what sense is my comparator incorrect?
I read on Oracle that the comparator "Compares its two arguments for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second."
I simply followed the description.

Comment: If you compare two squares, and they are not equal, then you should get the negated value for comparing them in reverse order - but the comparator is inconsistent.  Let's say I feed it an "apple" and an "orange".  I get the answer that apple > orange.  I feed it an "orange" and an "apple", then it tells me that orange > apple.  Inconsistency.

Comment: Do you know anywhere I can read more about this?
I compared the "accumulated cost" stored in the squares when I run my A* algorithm and it returns either -1, 0, 0r 1 bases on the comparison. 
The result seems correct, though. D:

Comment: @Sean: Simply read the documentation for `Comparable.compareTo`. For example: "The implementor must ensure sgn(x.compareTo(y)) == -sgn(y.compareTo(x)) for all x and y." That's *clearly* not the case with your implementation.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I guess I'll use a queue for now. ;)

Comment: I went to search for many more example and many, I mean, many websites teach the implementation involving -1,0,1. Maybe what you mentioned is peculiar to the Comparable class but not the Comparator class?

Comment: @Sean it should be -1,0 and 1. The problem with your implementation is  that `compareTo(square1, square2) == 1` and `compareTo(square2, square1) == 1`. So its impossible to understand which one is greater - `square1` or `square2`? if `compareTo(square1, square2) == 1` then `compareTo(square2, square1)` should be `-1`