# Java: a comparator always return 1 doesn't make a priority queue into a queue?

Tags: java, priority-queue, comparator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: strange order of queue made from priority queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12720293/java-strange-order-of-queue-made-from-priority-queue)

I tired to turn a priority queue into a queue by implementing the following comparator:

- Hack: The QueueComparator makes a PriorityQueue behaves like queue
          (FIFO) by always return 1
- Since the "natural ordering" of a priority queue has the least 
          element at the head and a conventional comparator returns -1 when 
          the first is less than the second, the hacked comparator always 
          return 1 so that the current (last) square will be placed at the 
          tail (recursively)

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Comparator;
public class QueueComparator implements Comparator<Square>{
    public int compare(Square square1, Square square2)
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

But the resulting "queue" does not keep things in order(FIFO). Why?

Comment: When you need a FIFO data structure, you could use a LinkedList.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The question is why should it?

First your Comparator is completely broken, since it violates the basic constraint that

```
sign(compare(a,b)) = - sign(compare(b,a))
```

and

```
compare(a,a) == 0
```

So anything using it might come up with all kinds of results like loosing entries, running in an endless loop, throwing a stackoverflow ...

If you want to implement a `IDontGiveAShitComparator` it should return 0 all the time. Everything depending on a Comparator should be able to handle that.

What order results is still up to the implementation. If it stores elements in a list FIFO or LIFO are kind of probable, If it stores in a balanced tree, it will probably add elements always on one side, causing rebalancing of the tree, which will pretty much mix everything up.

Maybe it uses something based on hashes, in which case all elements with the same priority might come out ordered by their hash values.

Comment: Thanks Jens. I did not dig into the laws behind the comparator and you are correct. :j

Answer (score 4):

Well, it's a hack. So if it's not working, I wouldn't be too surprised.

The [Javadoc of PriorityQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) says:

> The head of this queue is the least element with respect to the specified ordering. If multiple elements are tied for least value, the head is one of those elements -- **ties are broken arbitrarily**.

Well, there you have it. If your comparator returns the same value for all pairs of elements, you have nothing but ties. So the queue order is indeed arbitrary.

Comment: Nope, return a positive number indicates that obj1 > obj2, and return 0 indicates the tied situation.

Comment: @Sean Correct... Seems I wasn't thinking straight. But at least four people (the four the gave me a +1) neither. ;-)

Comment: Hahaha, this says a lot about politics in this world.

Answer (score 4):

`compareTo(a,b)` should in general return `-compare(b,a)`, and `compareTo(a,a)` should return zero. Your comparator breaks both these rules.

Check the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare%28T,%20T%29).

Answer (score 0):

A common implementation for a Priority Queue is done using a [Binary Heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap) (so does the default Java Implementation). The comparator is only used for keeping the Heap Property (a node is always greater/equal (or less/equal) to all its childen) true. If the comparator will always return 1 the behaviour of the PriotityQueue may lead to unexpected behaviour while trying to restore the Heap Property after an insert but will not end in a FIFO Queue.

Be aware that there is no real "tail" in a BinaryHeap as it is organized as a tree. Elements that should come last are the leaf nodes but not "at the end".